# Debugging Tools/Method for Mac OS X Interface Builder (3.2.3)

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder, nib, inspector

I am new to Mac OS X programming and so I am going through an introductory text that includes building interfaces using Interface Builder (3.2.3) for both Cocoa and Carbon.  Unfortunately I am having problems getting some of the examples I type in to run error free in the Cocoa and Carbon simulators.  So I tried downloading the source code files from the publisher's website and found that they ran with no problems.

I'm trying to find the differences between the publisher's working and my non-working versions of the code.  I started by just trying to compare the attribute settings as listed in Inspector but I could not find any differences.  I then came across File Merge which I used to compare the .nib files for the two different versions.  File Merge does show the differences but since I am unfamiliar with the markup language used in the .nib file and it lists too many differences to track down without being knowledgeable enough to know what is relevant or not, it really hasn't been very helpful.

My question is whether or not there is a tool or method available that will better show me the differences in the two versions of the code than what I can see in the Inspector window but also shows it in a more condensed and user friendly form than what is provided by File Merge.  What is the recommended tool/methodology to debugging code in Interface Builder?

Also, can anyone recommend documentation where I can become familiar with reading and debugging the code in the .nib file in case that is the only way to find the differences?

Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, there is no “simulator” for Mac development except in IB itself, where what you type (source code) has no effect. IB only presents what's in the nib, so your custom subclasses of NSView and HIView, not to mention custom controllers and model objects, are not present. When you run your app in Xcode, you are not simulating anything; you are really running your app on your real system.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [nib2objc](http://kosmaczewski.net/projects/nib2objc/)

Convert both yours and the example nibs to code.
It will convert nib files to what looks more like Obj-C code. Then just diff sections of them and see what's different. Should be pretty easy to read code vs NIB files.

Comment: If he's building a sample from a book, I'm willing to wager it's UIKit based. ;)

Comment: He mentions Mac OS X and Carbon, so no, I don't think it's UIKit based.

Answer (score 0):

The command line program `ibtool` can convert a nib into a text format, but I don't know if that will be sufficiently readable.